# Data is not displayed on the browser from the blockchain server on solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

I am trying to make a voting app using Blockchain on truffle framework. The data from the network is not rendered on the webpage. 
Only loading is displayed but the actual content is not displayed even though I have connected by Blockchain accounts from Ganache to my metamask extension. 
Here is my code:

Election.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Election {
    // Model a Candidate for first past the post system
    struct Candidatepost {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    // Model as candidate for proportional party system
    struct Candidateparty {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    // Store accounts that have voted
    mapping(address => bool) public voters;
    // Store Candidates
    // Fetch Candidate
    mapping(uint => Candidatepost) public cand_post;

    mapping(uint => Candidateparty) public cand_party;

    // Store Candidates Count
    uint public partyCount;
    uint public postCount;
    uint[] public candidatesCount = [postCount,partyCount];

    constructor () public {
        addpostCandidate("Candidate 1");
        addpostCandidate("Candidate 2");
        addpartyCandidate("Candidate 1");
        addpartyCandidate("Candidate 2");
        candidatesCount = [postCount,partyCount];
    }

    function addpostCandidate (string memory _name) private {
        postCount ++;
        cand_post[postCount] = Candidatepost(postCount, _name, 0);
    }


    function addpartyCandidate (string memory _name) private {
        partyCount ++;
        cand_party[partyCount] = Candidateparty(partyCount, _name, 0);
    }
    // voted event
    event votedEvent (
        uint indexed _candidateId1,
        uint indexed _candidateId2
    );


    function vote (uint _candidateId1, uint _candidateId2) public {
        // require that they haven't voted before
        require(!voters[msg.sender]);

        // require a valid candidate
        require(_candidateId1 > 0 && _candidateId1 <= postCount && _candidateId2 > 0 && _candidateId2 <= partyCount);

        // record that voter has voted
        voters[msg.sender] = true;

        // update candidate vote Count
        cand_post[_candidateId1].voteCount ++;
        cand_party[_candidateId2].voteCount ++;   
        // trigger voted event
        emit votedEvent(_candidateId1, _candidateId2);
    }
}
```

App.js

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: '0x0',
  init: function() {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    // TODO: refactor conditional
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }

    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON("Election.json", function(election) {
      // Instantiate a new truffle contract from the artifact
      App.contracts.Election = TruffleContract(election);
      // Connect provider to interact with contract
      App.contracts.Election.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      App.listenForEvents();

      return App.render();
    });
  },
  // Listen for events emitted from the contract
  listenForEvents: function() {
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      // Restart Chrome if you are unable to receive this event
      // This is a known issue with Metamask
      // https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2393
      instance.votedEvent({}, {
        fromBlock: 0,
        toBlock: 'latest'
      }).watch(function(error, event) {
        console.log("event triggered", event)
        // Reload when a new vote is recorded
        App.render();
      });
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var electionInstance;
    var loader = $("#loader");
    var content = $("#content");

    loader.show();
    content.hide();

    // Load account data
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
      }
    });

    //load contract data
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      electionInstance = instance;

      return electionInstance.candidatesCount();
    }).then(function(1) {


      var postcandidatesResults = $("#postcandidatesResults");
      postcandidatesResults.empty();
      var partycandidatesResults = $("#partycandidatesResults");
      partycandidatesResults.empty();

      var postcandidatesSelect = $('#postcandidatesSelect');
      postcandidatesSelect.empty();
      var partycandidatesSelect = $('#partycandidatesSelect');
      partycandidatesSelect.empty();

      for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

        electionInstance.cand_post(i).then(function(candidate) {
          var id = candidate[0];
          var name = candidate[1];
          var voteCount = candidate[2];

          // Render candidate Result
          var candidateTemplate = "<tr><th>" + id + "</th><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + voteCount + "</td></tr>";
          postcandidatesResults.append(candidateTemplate);

          // Render candidate ballot option
          var candidateOption = "<option value='" + id + "' >" + name + "</ option>";
          postcandidatesSelect.append(candidateOption);
        });
      }
      for (var j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        electionInstance.cand_party(i).then(function(candidate) {
          var id2 = candidate[0];
          var name2 = candidate[1];
          var voteCount2 = candidate[2];

          // Render candidate Result
          var candidateTemplate2 = "<tr><th>" + id2 + "</th><td>" + name2 + "</td><td>" + voteCount2 + "</td></tr>";
          partycandidatesResults.append(candidateTemplate2);

          // Render candidate ballot option
          var candidateOption2 = "<option value='" + id2 + "' >" + name2 + "</ option>";
          partycandidatesSelect.append(candidateOption2);
        });
      }

      return electionInstance.voters(App.account);
    }).then(function(hasVoted) {
      // Do not allow a user to vote
      if(hasVoted) {
        $('form').hide();
      }
      loader.hide();
      content.show();
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.warn(error);
    });
  },
  castVote: function() {
    var candidateId1 = $('#postcandidatesSelect').val();
    var candidateId2 = $('#partycandidatesSelect').val();
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.vote(candidateId1, candidateId2, { from: App.account });
    }).then(function(result) {
      // Wait for votes to update
      $("#content").hide();
      $("#loader").show();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }

};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Election Results</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="width: 650px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="text-center">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center" style="border:none;background:white;">
      <div class="col-md-1 col-3">
        <img class="mx-auto d-block  img-fluid" src="images/logo.png" style=""   alt="">
      </div>
    </div></h1>
          <hr/>
          <br/>

          <h1 class="text-center">National Election-2075</h1>
          <h1 class="text-center">Election Updates</h1>
          <div id="loader">
            <p class="text-center">Loading...</p>
          </div>
          <div id="content" style="display: none;">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Votes</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="postcandidatesResults">
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr/>
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Votes</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="partycandidatesResults">
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr/>
            <form onSubmit="App.castVote(); return false;">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="postcandidatesSelect">Select Candidate</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="postcandidatesSelect">
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="partycandidatesSelect">Select Candidate</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="partycandidatesSelect">
                </select>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Vote</button>
              <hr />
            </form>
            <p id="accountAddress" class="text-center"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share the errors and some screenshots. That will help us understand the question better.

Comment: I guess you are missing the async and await for the javascript calls

Answer (score 0):

Any call to the blockchain is async(returns a promise).  You need to either handle the promise with a .then()  or you can use async await.  Basically anything chained after electionInstance is async.  For example:

```
 electionInstance.candidatesCount();
 electionInstance.cand_party
 electionInstance.voters
```